# SQL parse error when using "WITH CHANGE DATA FEED" on Databricks

Tags: sql, databricks

This works:

```
ALTER SHARE my_share ADD TABLE main.default.my_table;
```

This doesn't:

```
ALTER SHARE my_share ADD TABLE main.default.my_table WITH CHANGE DATA FEED;
```

But according to the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data-sharing/delta-sharing/index.html#add-or-remove-tables-from-a-share) it should. But I get a "ParseException" and no further details.

What's the right syntax?

The cluster is running Databricks Runtime 10.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS.